# No new data after a RealTime update, and missing recent posts in OpenGraph /feed

Tags: facebook, real-time, facebook-opengraph

I'm having a hard time getting access to most recent posts and comments for a given user using the OpenGraph API. 
I have the `read_stream` permission, and get realtime notifications for `feed` field on the `user` object. The notification comes in, but fetching the `/<user id>/feed` stream doesn't include the new action.

When playing around with the Graph API Explorer, the data I see via OpenGraph and data I see by going directly to the page is different. Viewing my friend's profile, I see his latest update, yet it doesn't come back via `/friend_id/feed`. A comment I left a week ago shows in my `/feed`, but one from a few hours ago (which sent a realtime notification!) isn't showing up.

It's almost like some posts are filtered for the API. Is this how it's supposed to work?

My actual goal is to get all the comments made by my application's user.